# Boot-repair Boot Info

Tags: grub2, boot-repair

While installing freeBSD alongside Ubuntu installation on hdd, system boots grub shell and resign to boot grub menu further.

Boor-Repair reported errors, please look at me boot info http://paste.ubuntu.com/6154175/

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Run Boot-Repair --> Advanced options --> "`GRUB options`" tab --> tick "`Purge and reinstall GRUB`" --> Apply